# replicas=1 - does it mean 1 pod or 1 pod + 1 replica running?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I am using openshift 3.11
In the spec below I got from https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/core_concepts/deployments.html,
does it mean 1 pod is running, or 1 pod + 1 replica is running?

[image]

Comment: 1 POD. That’s it. BTW, please replace the image with formatted text as it helps in searching.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question yes 1 pod is running and 1 RC. Replicas=1 is nothing but you mean no matter what you want at least 1 pod should be running and this is your desired number of pod. and replica is nothing but running identical pods which are managed by replication controller.

**In nutshell to above explanation, 1 pod is running and 1 RC is running(who manages that pod)**

Here I have deployed and reproduced your scenario.

I got one RC

[image]

Here one POD

[image]

But the best practice is to use DeploymentConfig instead of using replicationController directly.

DeploymentConfig manage replicationcontroller and replication controller manages pod directly.

DeploymentConfig >> ReplicationController >> POD

In openshift still have RC not replicaset for DeploymentConfig
Here is DeploymentConfig

[image]

here is RC for my DeploymentConfig

[image]

and here is pod

[image]

Comment: `ReplicationController` is deprecated and replaced by `ReplicaSet`. And there’s no such object as `DeploymentConfig`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar In Openshift still use RC not replicaset

Comment: Are you sure? https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/architecture/core_concepts/deployments.html#replica-set

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Please check the answer correct. I am talking about DeploymentConfig and yes even if you deploy replicationController we have 1 RC and 1 pod try it !!